# Unable to drop a metric in prometheus using regex in service monitor yaml on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

Team,
I have metrics being pulled in prometheus successfully but i want to drop some and seems like am not able to understand how to match regex to drop a **name** metric. any hint? or is my syntax not right?

QUERY is below

```
{__name__="mslicer_read_latency_sum"}
```

on prometheus query result is below

```
mslicer_read_latency_sum{endpoint="admin",instance="11.1.1.1:8",job="tsts",namespace="tests",pod="tests",service="experiments"} 0
```

my servicemonitor is like this below to drop above but i see it is not getting dropped. so any hint if my regex is wrong?

```
  spec:
    endpoints:
    - interval: 30s
      metricRelabelings:
      - action: drop
        regex: mslicer_read_latency_sum
        sourceLabels:
        - __name__
```